# Error from inside the Android tools, check the console

Tags: android, processing, processing-ide

Using the Processing IDE to write Processing apps for Android, I sometimes bump my head against this problem.

In the Processing IDE output window is usually something like:

```
BUILD FAILED
/Users/xxxxx/Tools/android-sdk-macosx/tools/ant/build.xml:850: The following error occurred while executing this line:
/Users/xxxxx/Tools/android-sdk-macosx/tools/ant/build.xml:852: The following error occurred while executing this line:
/Users/xxxxx/Tools/android-sdk-macosx/tools/ant/build.xml:864: The following error occurred while executing this line:
/Users/xxxxx/Tools/android-sdk-macosx/tools/ant/build.xml:266: null returned: 1
```

In most cases I can backtrack and rectify it but it's not a very informative error report. I've tried to figure out how I "check the console" but have failed in this regard.

Where is this mythical console and how to I "check it"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you asking how to check the Android DDMS debugger (allowing you to view processes and cpu, etc on your device) ?
Or how to open the OS X Console (which will just repeat what the Processing console says...) ?

For DDMS, run the DDMS shell inside your /tools directory in your SDK.
For OSX, open the 'Console.app' in /Applications/Utilities

Generally though this error message in Processing just means it didn't compile - ie. there is a problem with your code... (NPE, etc).

Comment: Thanks. I was referring specifically to OS X console. Since it is a build error, it hasn't got as far as the Android device yet. I have explored the OS X console on your suggestion, you're right, it just reflects the Processing console. So, though the OS X console is not helpful in this case, I'm accepting your answer. But that leaves me with very obscure build errors! In this case I'm compiling with `java.util.Observable` and `java.util.Observable` which, as far as I can tell, should be fine. Perhaps a topic for another question!

Comment: Oh, I meant to add, thanks for the tip re Android DDMS debugger - that's going to be useful.